# Counting problem of unique asigments

Tags: combinatorics

I have to solve a counting problem but since my math skills are unfortunately low, I'm afraid I have stuck on a wall.

Since the outcome could be `0` I don't know if this is even a combinatorics problem. Here is the problem.

I have `4` people and `4` Tasks. I know that each people must perform `2` taks and that each thask must be performed by `2` people. I must found all the distinct assigments. Since this could be `0` I don't know if this is a combinatorics problem.

This is what I was thinking:

I have `4` tasks so this is what if tought

```
4*3     4*3     2*1     2*1
___     ___     ___     ___
```

For the first task since there must be `2` people on each task we have `4` possible people and after that, `3` possible people;
For the second task, the same since one people can perform `2` tasks;
And so on...

Since we ant unique assignments I've divided the above result by `4!`.

$$\frac{4*3*4*3*2*1*2*1}{4!}$$

Is this by any way the correct solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't assign a number to the people, or the tasks, then the answer is only two distinct assignments. [(1,2) (1,2) (3,4) (3,4)] and [(1,2) (1,3) (2,4) (3,4)]

I imagined a tetrahedron, which can be rotated any way, with each vertex representing a task.